# jQuery input function not always firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I'm using `.on('input', function (e){...});` to see when the text in a textfield input has changed. Though this isn't always working. Sometimes when I write something, no alert box shows up.

When refreshing and testing the page a few times it works most of the time but not 100%.

I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X2Jg4/5/) for you to try. Look under External Recources and you can see that I'm using a gist because I use an external .js file on my site too.

Here is an example of it not working, notice the refresh button
[image]

I'm using Google Chrome 32.0.1700.107 on OS X 10.9.1

Comment: Under what circumstances is it not working?

Comment: Just sometimes when I try to input some text, no alert box shows up.

Comment: Works fine 100% for me (Firefox Aurora 28.0)

Comment: If I hit space, the text box appears until I let go of the spacebar. Then the text box disappears. Is that what you mean? Perhaps a `console.log()` would be a better indicator of whether the event has fired?

Comment: Try to change event in your plugin to: this.on('keyup', function(e){alert('changed');});

Comment: Added an image to better illustrate what I mean. @Pavlo still not working.

Comment: Working fine here latest Chrome (Linux)